# Reason for span tags in Bootstrap nav bar header

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I was learning bootstrap from w3schools. Please find the link.
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h

In this link, in nav bar header I could notice the span tag as

```
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
```

it is used more than once in nav bar header. I removed those span tags from code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                             
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Still the code is responsive and no visible changes were there.. Is there any use of it? 
Also could you please simply explain why class "sr-only" is used? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"icon-bar"` is used for creating so called "burger" (like this ≡) on mobile devices - it creates button with short horizontral lines with dropdown instead of wide original menu

`"sr-only"` means "screen-reader only":

> Screen readers will have trouble with your forms if you don't include
>   a label for every input. For these inline forms, you can hide the
>   labels using the .sr-only class.

Answer (score 0):

The "sr-only" class is a tag that makes the content hidden except for "reader-devices" or "read-view" in some browsers.

Comment: Thank you for the reply... Could you please explain what "Content is hidden"?

Answer (score 0):

Try to restore down your browser and minimize browser windows area as small as possible. `nav-bar` will change to responsive layout like in the up-right corner of this image.

[image]

```
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
```

gives this view to responsive menu. And `sr-only` means screen reader only. Screen readers will have trouble with your forms if you don't include a label for every input.